# Make old posts visible only for my circle on Google+

Tags: privacy, google-plus

How can I make my old posts on Google+ visible only for those people I have added in my circle?

Comment: Having the same problem, very frustrating. I want to share a page I made with a group, but new circle members aren't seeing the older posts (prior to their addition to the circle)

Answer (score 15):

There isn't a way to change the visibility of existing posts. Once they've been posted they're "out there" and visible to everyone you shared them with in the first place. The only thing you could do is delete it and then repost to the correct circles/people.

For new posts click on the `[x]` in the "Public" green button and then click on

> + Add circles or people to share with

Then just pick those people or circles you want.

Comment: You can't change the sharing state of existing posts. The only thing you can do is delete and re-post.

Comment: This is a very weird implemented feature, what if we wan't to show the post to new people? why google decides about visibility of our own posts?  should we repost every time we want to change scope? is it a way to encourage us to make all public? hate to say this but facebook is better at this point